# Assign string that contains quote to variable

Tags: r

I need to assign `]<"` string to variable.

I tried:

```
a <- "]<\"")
```

But `print(a)` outputs `"]<\""` instead of `"]<""`.

So how to assign `]<"` string to variable?

Comment: R will always show the escape character '\', thus `"]<\""` is correct.  If you don't believe it, save "a" to a file and then open the file with any text editor.

Comment: @Dave2e You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use single quotes or escape the quote

```
a <- ']<"'
a
#> [1] "]<\""

a <- "]<\""
a
#> [1] "]<\""
```

Comment: But you get `"]<\""` and not `"]<""`. I need to put `]<"` string in variable.

Comment: it is just printed with the escaped character. the string itself is as expected

Comment: You can see this e.g. with `cat(a)`

Answer (score 0):

To save file in text file in order to find that above answers and coments are right:

```
fileConn<-file("D:/output.txt")
writeLines(a, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Comment: Or just `writeLines(a)` and it will print to the screen in your R session.